# How can I display pop up information when I hover the other areas in the map?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Here's my code for HTML CSS and Javascript and my problem is that I can only display the pop up when I hover one area but when I hover to the other area that is mapped it doesn't display the pop up. I've searched the internet for solutions but all I can find is jquery solutions which we are not allowed to use because we are only allowed to use javascript for this without using any libraries. I would gladly appreciate your help addressing my problem. Thank you and have a good day!

```js
let img = document.querySelectorAll("#oval, #amphi");
let title = document.querySelectorAll("#oval, #amphi");
let descr = document.querySelectorAll("#oval, #amphi");
let modal = document.getElementById("myModal"); 



function openModal(title,img,descr)
{
    
    if(modal=document.querySelector("#oval")){
        document.getElementById("myModal").style.display="block";
        document.getElementById("title").textContent=title;
        document.getElementById("content").src=img;
        document.getElementById("dscr").innerHTML=descr;
        }
    
    else if(modal=document.querySelector("#amphi")){
        document.getElementById("myModal").style.display="block";
        document.getElementById("title").textContent=title;
        document.getElementById("content").src=img;
        document.getElementById("dscr").innerHTML=descr;
        }
    
}

    

function closeModal()
{
        if(modal.target.id!=document.getElementById("pupoval")){
            document.getElementById("myModal").style.display="none";
        }
        
        else if(modal.target.id!=document.getElementById("amphi")){
            document.getElementById("myModal").style.display="none";
        }
}
```

```css
body{
    margin:0;
}

.modal{
    display:none;
    position:absolute;
    z-index:1;
    left:0;
    top:0;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    overflow:auto;
}

.modal-container{
    background-color:#FFFFCC;
    margin: 10% auto;
    padding: 15px;
    width: 500px;
    box-shadow: 0 5px 8px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2), 0 7px 20px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.17);
    animation-name: openModal;
    animation-duration: 10ms;
}

.modal-body{
    background-color: white;
    border-style:solid;
    border-color:black;
    border-width:5px;
    margin:0;
    height:300px;
}

.modal-header{
    background-color:#A60500;
    font-family: Verdana;
    text-align:center;
    color:white;
    width:50%;
    height:10%;

}

.modal-footer{
    background-color:#ccaa50;
    font-family: Comic Sans;
    font-weight:bold;
}

@keyframes openModal(
    from{ opacity:0}
    to{ opacity:1}
)
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    <meta content='text/html ;charset=utf-8'/>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"/>
    <link href='map.css' type='text/css' rel='stylesheet'/>
    <script language = "JavaScript" type = "text/javascript" src = "pmap.js">
    </script>
    <title> PUP MAP </title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <img src ="https://pupchem.weebly.com/uploads/6/8/8/4/6884332/9569207.gif?567" width="566" height="425" alt="PUP MAP"  usemap="#pupmap">
        <map name="pupmap">
            <area id="pupoval" shape ="poly" coords="363,312,409,245,422,234,435,229,452,228,463,231,469,235,479,243,488,254,492,268,492,279,489,294,445,358,432,369,422,374,405,376,387,371,376,363,367,351,360,329,363,315" alt="Oval" href="#" onmouseover="openModal('Oval','https://i2.wp.com/www.theurbanroamer.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/10/dsc01278.jpg','This is where students perform physical activities and where events are held.')"
onmouseout ="closeModal()"/>
            
            <area id="amphi" shape="poly" coords="204,223,233,227,231,235,225,240,218,243,214,242,208,241,201,236,198,229,199,222" 
            alt="Amphitheater" href="#"onmouseover="openModal('Amphitheater','https://kilosparty.files.wordpress.com/2007/06/amphi.jpg?w=375&h=250','This place is where some performance of students take place like public speech.')" onmouseout="closeModal()"/>
        </map>
        
        <div id="myModal" class='modal'>
            <div class='modal-container'>
                <div class='modal-header'>
                    <h2 id='title'></h2>
                </div>
                <div class='modal-body'>
                        <img id = "content" src ="" width="490" height="300" alt="Location" >
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <p id ='dscr'></p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Works fine for me in Chrome. Both the areas marked (1) as well as (24) show their respective popup.

Comment: You are assigning inside an `if`, is that intentional? It's valid JS, but is almost always a typo where the author meant to do a logical comparison: `if(modal=document.querySelector("#oval"))`

Comment: @CBroe When I open it in microsoft edge it doesn't appear and when I run the code snippet here and view it in full page it worked fine.